# QT Unclear shift-operator behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, bit-shift

I need to get 2 high bits from one byte in array. I have enum, that defines all values of those 2 bits:

```
...
enum elems{
    elem1 = 0,
    elem2 = 1,
    elem3 = 2,
    elem4 = 3
}
...
elems getElems(const QByteArray &data)
{
    return (elems)(data[3] >> 6);
}
...
qDebug() << (data[3] >> 6); // return 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 (true way)
qDebug() << getElems(data); // return 0 or 1 or -1 or -2 (wrong way)
...
```

When `data[3] == 0` it return `0`, when `data[3] == 64` it return `1`, but when `data[3] == 192` it return `-1` and when `data[3] == 128` it return `-2`.

Why it's happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QByteArray` is an array to `char`, which most probably is signed. Therefore 192 is outside `char`'s range and wraps back to -64

When you `return (elems)(data[3] >> 6)` it will do an [arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) like most compiler implementations on a signed type (because [right shift in C++ is implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522346/995714)). That will propagate the sign bit (1 in this case because of -64) to the left, making all the bits in the byte 1 and is the reason why you see -1 returned.

If you only want the 2 high bits, mask the result before returning

```
return (elems)((data[3] >> 6) & 0x03);
```

Or cast the type to unsigned

```
return (elems)((qint8)data[3] >> 6);
```

Alternatively this will also work

```
return (elems)((data[3] >> 6) & 0xFF);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lưu Vĩnh Phúc is correct. you can also modify your function as:

```
return (elems)((unsigned char)data[3] >> 6);
```

Comment: it's correct. Right shift on unsigned type is always logical shift. Only shifts on signed type may be arithmetic