# Integer and subpixel shift

Tags: image-processing, integer, bit-shift, subpixel

I wanted to know what integer shift is?

And what is the difference between integer and subpixel shifts in the image processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have seen this in an image processing literature, then no, it does not mean what it [generally means in computer science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522346/right-shift-and-signed-integer).

The likely thing is that you have seen this somewhere where the images are "shifted". The shift (moving a pixel to a different location) can be done by moving the entire pixel to the location of the adjacent pixel, being this an integer movement, because you have moved it by 1 pixel. Or it can be done by moving the pixel by less than this (probably using interpolation to generate a new image). If you do this, you are moving the image in subpixel (less than pixel) motion.

In the following diagram, images N1-4 have subpixel sifts, as each square (pixel) is far from the others by non-integer distances
[image: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Feng_Ling2/publication/236232666/figure/fig3/AS:299365374676994@1448385675212/a-Four-images-of-2-A-2-pixels-with-sub-pixel-shifts-x-and-y-represent-the-image.png]

Comment: Hi Andre, Thanks for your complete answer, it was what I had been looking for!!!.